# How to call Simple Systems Manager 'RUN COMMAND' from within AWS Lambda Python

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

There is a document in system manager which is used to kill the process running inside the EC2 Instance and it is working correctly through AWS Console.Everytime i used to put the value the service to kill and it is killing it. But I want to revoke this System Manager "Run Command" from the Lambda.

Please help me.. I am new on Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Lambda function's IAM role has SSM related necessary permissions, you can use the AWS SDK for the SSM service to run the SSM document to solve your purpose. For example, if you're using Python runtime for your Lambda function, you initiate a Boto3 SSM client, and use [send_command()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.send_command) to run the SSM document you wish to run. Hope this helps!